# If the largest positive integer is n such that $\sqrt{n - 100} + \sqrt{n + 100}$ is a rational no. , find the value of $\sqrt{n - 1}$ .

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, sums-of-squares

So here is the Problem :-

If the largest positive integer is n such that $\sqrt{n - 100} + \sqrt{n + 100}$ is a rational no. , find the value of $\sqrt{n - 1}$ .

**What I tried :-** I think that for $\sqrt{n - 100} + \sqrt{n + 100}$ to be a rational no. , both $(n - 100)$ and $(n + 100)$ have to be squares. Suppose :- $(n - 100)$  = $k^2$ and $(n + 100)$ = $m^2$ for some positive integers $k,m$  , and in the end I could only deduce that $(m + 10)(m - 10) = k^2 + 100$ , but then I couldn't proceed .

Also by guesswork, I could deduce that for $n = 125$, both nos. do become squares, although I don't know whether $n = 125$ is the highest or not.

Any hints or explanations to this problem will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: This looks like a good start. Note that if $n\pm100$ are squares as you say then $$200=m^2-k^2=(m+k)(m-k)$$

Comment: Oh yeah!, @PeterForeman , I totally forgot about that . I actually had got before that $$m^2 - 100 = k^2 + 100$$ .

Comment: It's generally a good idea to wait some time before choosing the best answer, just to give other people enough time to provide their answer (unless this is some kind of speed competition).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{n-100} + \sqrt{n+100} = p$, where $p$ is rational.
$$\implies 2n + 2\sqrt{n^2 - 10000} = p^2$$
But that must mean that $2\sqrt{n^2 - 10000}$ is rational.

Which must mean that $\sqrt{n^2 - 10000}$ is rational.
$$\implies n^2 - 10000 = k^2$$
$$\implies (n+k)(n-k) = 10000$$ The problem requires us to maximize $n$, notice that we'll get the maximum value of $n$ if we split $10000 = 5000 \times 2$ and set $n+k = 5000$ and $n-k = 2$ to get $n = 2501$.

Hence, $\boxed{\sqrt{n-1} = 50}$

Comment: Excellent and the quickest solution . Thank you!

Comment: $k$ is rational or integer?

Comment: @Aqua $k$ has to be an integer as $n$ in an integer.

Comment: Ok , so the equation changes to $$(n + \frac{k}{2})(n - \frac{k}{2}) = 10000$$

Comment: Yes but hos do you know $x$ square of an integer. Say $x=8$ is ok.

Comment: @Anonymous You don't need to change it.

Comment: @Aqua because the square root of $8$ is irrational? You're confusing $\sqrt{2x}$ with $2\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Aqua If the square root of an integer is a rational then this square root is also an integer.

Comment: Why would $2\sqrt{x}$ be a perfect square? I merely said that it's rational and for it to be rational, $x$ must be a perfect square. I hope this clears it?

Comment: Yes of course, but $k$ is not an integer

Comment: Why do you think so? $n$ is an integer as stated in the problem. $10000$ is definitely an integer. What can you say about the difference of squares of two integers?

Comment: @Aqua $2\sqrt{n^2 - 10000}$ is a rational. So $\sqrt{n^2 - 10000}$ is also a rational $c$. As $n^2 - 10000$ is an integer, this rational $c$ has to be an integer: if $\sqrt m = a/b$ with $a,b$ coprime, then $b^2 m = a^2$ and $b | a$.

Comment: "we'll get the maximum value of $n$ if we split $10000 = 5000 \times 2$" - you might want to elaborate more on that, why do you get maximum value this way? Did you try them all? Not saying it's wrong, but it might improve the answer.

Comment: Well, if you would write that down in an answer there would be no confusion. Writing just like that someone could think you are not aware of this steps.

Comment: @Aqua This perfectly makes sense and would had avoided this list of comments!

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it is not stright forvard to say $n+100$ and $n-100$ are squares.

Put it this way:
$$\sqrt{n - 100} + \sqrt{n + 100}=r\in\mathbb{Q}$$
now we square it:

$$n-100+2\sqrt{n^2-100}+n+100 = r^2$$ and so $$ \sqrt{n^2-100} = {r^2\over 2}-n$$ Now we square it again and we get:
$$-100= {r^4\over 4}-r^2n$$ Now let $r={a\over b}$ where $a,b$ are relativly prime positive integers. So:
$$a^2(4nb^2-a^2)=400b^4\implies b^2(4n-400b^2)= a^4$$ and thus $$b\mid a^4\implies b=1$$
Now we have $$a^2(4n-a^2)=400\implies a\mid 400\implies a\in\{1,2,4,5,8, 10,20\}$$

Now check each possible $a$ and you are done.

Comment: I got your point . But @Nikunj's solution was the best .

Comment: But his solution lack of steps. If someone would have to grade it it should not give him all points.

Comment: His solution do lacks some steps, but anybody reading his solution can understand it easily .